TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON when accessing $slot data from a Child component in VueJS 3
Problem: <pre>{{ $slots.title() }}</pre> is not printing out the expected object.
My parent component
ModalView.vue
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Modal from '@/components/Modal.vue'
import { btnStyleDark } from '@/styles/tailwindStyles'

const showModal = ref(false)
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Modals</h1>
    <button @click="showModal = true" :class="btnStyleDark">Show Modal</button>

    <Modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false" :btn-style="btnStyleDark">
      <template #title>My new title</template>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel tempora quibusdam tenetur,
        debitis autem fugit a nesciunt mollitia ipsa inventore nostrum perspiciatis neque dolor id
        magnam facere eum similique? Adipisci.
      </p>
    </Modal>
  </div>
</template>

My child component
Modal.vue
<script setup>
import { defineProps, defineEmits } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  btnStyle: String,
})

const emit = defineEmits(['close'])
</script>

<template>
  <teleport to="#modals-container">
    <div class="modal z-10 absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full p-10 bg-yellow-50">
      <h1><slot name="title" /></h1>
      <slot />
      <pre>{{ $slots.title() }}</pre>
      <button :class="btnStyle" @click="$emit('close')">Hide modal</button>
    </div>
  </teleport>
</template>

Error in chrome:

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
|     property 'vnode' -> object with constructor 'Object'
--- property 'component' closes the circle
at JSON.stringify ()
at toDisplayString (chunk-U6BEPC57.js?v=60065120:256:154)

If I remove the () from <pre>{{ $slots.title() }}</pre> inside the child I am able to see this printed in the <pre> tag on the page without an error:

However this data does not tell me anything and also does not match the data that is printed out from this course video:

What I've tried

Using the useSlots import
This produces the same error, but the first console.log does work!
<script setup>
import { defineProps, defineEmits, useSlots, onMounted } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  btnStyle: String,
})

const emit = defineEmits(['close'])

const slots = useSlots()

console.log(slots.title())

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(slots)
})
</script>

<template>
  <teleport to="#modals-container">
    <div class="modal z-10 absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full p-10 bg-yellow-50">
      <h1><slot name="title" /></h1>
      <slot />
      <pre>{{ $slots.title() }}</pre>
      <!-- <pre>{{ slots.title ? slots.title()[0] : '' }}</pre> -->

      <button :class="btnStyle" @click="$emit('close')">Hide modal</button>
    </div>
  </teleport>
</template>

I also tried <pre>{{ slots.title() }}</pre> without the $ and this still throws the error.

The question lacks clear problem statement. Do you have a goal you didn't mention, or want to debug slot contents, or just curious why  doesn't work?

I will update question, but basically I want what is printed out in the console.log(slots.title()) that entire object inside an array to be printed out in the pre, and not that un-readabled function

It seems it doesn't like to handle null values when it needs to display.
I use const slots = useSlots();
<div v-for="(value, key) in slots.title()[0]" :key="key">
  <strong>{{ key.toString() }}:</strong>
  {{ value ? value.toString() : "null" }}
</div>`

In my test phase, I created a simple function:
<button @click="close">Hide modal</button>

function close() {
  console.log(slots.title()[0]);
  emit("close");
}

And I got what you show in the udemy screenshot.
Little Hint to finish: I just noticed in your code that with Vue3, you declare the emit event, so you have to remove the '$' => @click="emit('close')"

Ah thanks yeah that did work, checking each key, for null.... I wonder if perhaps our difference is that I'm using Typescript, he isn't, but strange. Anyways thanks! I find it unlikely I would need to print out the slot data like this on the actual page, but good to know how to work around it :)
